# Android: Cache image by android class or manual way?

Tags: android, image, caching

When i develop a android app with download and caching image from internet, i see many app use MemoryLruCache or DiskLruCache to cache image after download. But i want to know why they use them, why don't use the way like: download image, then save image into sd card and after get image from sd card to show it( it is manual way).
I'm newbie in android dev. So please help me to understand it?
Thanks many many times.

Comment: I think that you need to fully understand first what is Cache and it's advantages : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

well downloading a list of images from url will consume time and also fill up the user memory also....so its better to dynamically load images from url and make its cache and then preview the images from cache..

I hope you did got my point....check some example of lazy loading of image

Comment: Thanks your comment. 
But i will download images and save into sd card. then get image from sd card, i also don't get image from internet again. But i think when we use cache to save it, it will load more than from sd card. Is that right?